# Import messages to archived user with gmail api

Tags: gmail-api

I am attempting to use the Gmail API to import messages to a user. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/import

I can do this successfully for most users using the following request. The bearer token is generated using a service account p12 certificate/key file. The scopes listed in the documentation have been setup.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/my.destination@domain.com/messages/import?uploadType=multipart&deleted=true HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer ya29.mytoken

{"labelIds":[]}
```

However, when I try to use this endpoint for a user flagged as archived, then I receive the following response.

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to import messages to an archived user? Are there additional steps needed to authenticate this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Archived users are just accounts that have data retained. Importing messages is not possible as their Gmail is put on hold.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on [Preserving data for users who leave your organization](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2736622?hl=en):

> If a user leaves your organization and you want to continue to retain or hold that user's data with Google Vault, a G Suite administrator should use Archived User (AU) to preserve the user’s data.
>
> Data is also preserved for a suspended account, but the account can receive no new messages.

Archiving a user places their Google Chat and Gmail on hold, as per [this documentaiton](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9048836) on managing for employee data. The process of placing Gmail messages on hold is detailed [here](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2473591)

#### References:

- [Preserving data for users who leave your organization - Google Vault Help](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2736622?hl=en)
- [Manage former employees and their data - G Suite Admin Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9048836)
- [Place Gmail messages on hold - Google Vault Help](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/2473591)